# Adding data to a program if exist; else do generate random data in java

Tags: java, math, random

I have a math program that shows random math problems, when you click to see the next answer the next answer appears.

I have added a method which uploads a file called upload.txt

I want my program to run the math problems in this file instead of running the random 
math problems if the file exist. If not I want the program to run the current way which is running the random math problems.

My current method for adding the text file is not 100 percent accurate. 
I wont to just take the problems written in the file to be added. I got it working just uploading numbers to the command prompt by using code from another thread on StackOverflow.

random math problems class

```
import java.util.Random;

public class MathProblems {
     private static final int MAX_NUMBER = 1000;
     private static final Random random = new Random();

     private double expected = 0;
     private String question = "";


     public void run() {
         final int a = random.nextInt(MAX_NUMBER);
         final int b = random.nextInt(MAX_NUMBER);

         final int type = random.nextInt(4);

         switch (type) {
             case 0: 
                 add(a, b);
                 break;
             case 1: 
                subtract(a, b);
                break;
             case 2:
                multiply(a, b);
                break;
             case 3:
                 divide(a, b);
                 break;
         }
     }

     private void add(final int a, final int b) {
         expected = a + b;

         askQuestion(a + " + " + b + " = ");
     }

     private void subtract(final int a, final int b) {
         expected = a - b;

         askQuestion(a + " - " + b + " = ");
     }

     private void multiply(final int a, final int b) {
         expected = a * b;

         askQuestion(a + " * " + b + " = ");
     }

     private void divide(final int a, final int b) {
         expected = (double)a / b; 

         askQuestion(a + " / " + b + " = ");
     }

     private  void askQuestion(final String question) {
         this.question = question;
     }  

     public String getQuestion() {
         return question;
     }

     @Override
     public String toString(){
     return Double.toString(expected);
     }
}
```

Driver Class

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Driver extends MathProblems {

        MathProblems problems = new MathProblems();

        Scanner textfile;

        String s = "Welcome Students!";
        String b = "Start!";
        private JFrame f;
        private JPanel p;

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        JButton b1 = new JButton(b);

        JLabel jl = new JLabel(s);

        int i;

        private int clicked;

        public Driver() {
                gui();
        }

        public void gui() {
                f = new JFrame("Flash Card Program");
                p = new JPanel();
                f.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
                f.add(jl);
                f.add(p);
                p.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
                p.add(b1);

                jl.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

                // pack the frame for better cross platform support
                f.pack();
                // Make it visible
                f.setVisible(true);
                f.setSize(500, 400); // default size is 0,0
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                                if (b1.getText().equals("Click For Answer")) {
                                        jl.setText(problems.toString());
                                        b = "Next Question";
                                        b1.setText(b);
                                } else {
                                        problems.run();
                                        jl.setText(problems.getQuestion());
                                        b = "Click For Answer";
                                        b1.setText(b);

                                }

                        }
                });

                b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                                if (clicked++ == 10) {

                                        Object[] options = { "No, thanks", "Yes, please" };

                                        int response = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame,
                                                        "Would you like more math questions? ",
                                                        "Math Questions", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
                                                        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options,
                                                        options[1]);

                                        if (response == 1)
                                                clicked = 0; // reset
                                        else
                                                System.exit(0);
                                }

                        }
                });

        }

        static void filereader(Scanner textfile) {         
                    int i = 0;         
                    int sum = 0;          
                    while(i <= 19)         
                    {       
                        int nextInt = textfile.nextInt();          

                        System.out.println(nextInt);             
                        sum = sum + nextInt;
                        i++;         
                    }     
                }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
                EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                                new Driver();

                Scanner textfile = null;
                try {
                    textfile = new Scanner(new File("upload.txt"));
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                filereader(textfile);
                }
                });
        }
}
```

.txt file

```
1 + 1
2 + 2
3 + 3
4 + 4
5 + 5
6 + 6
7 + 7
8 + 8
9 + 9
10 + 10
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question? Do you currently get an error? If so, can you post that error? Is there specific portion of the code we should be looking at?

Comment: Yes the method that is uploading the .txt file. I am trying to add these problems in the txt file to the program instead of running the random math problems. If the file exist.

Comment: I know that the method filereader is not correct. Instead of doing any math I just want the problems to take the place of the random Math being controlled from the random math class

Comment: I'm not clear on what you want, but you've told your program to read a bunch of integers from the file, and you've posted an input file that has things other than integers.  Try looking at the javadoc for the [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class.

Comment: so if i just change it to 1 - 10 could i have it just set those ints to the math problem, like 1+1.

Comment: Some general advice: get yourself a good Java debugger, and learn to use it. It's the best way to track down these kinds of problems.

Comment: bro I know what the problem is. I don't know how to achieve my goal. I am asking how this would be done. Instead of running the program with random math problems using the randomMath class how can I use a if else statement to use integers inside of a txt file. with the exception that if the file does not exist then it just runs the program with the randomMath problems.

Comment: My program runs fine... I am trying to implement a new method and I can not figure out the logical way to do this or how to write the method correctly. That is what I am asking someone to help me with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a global vector of question values for each of a and b.  A nicer way to do this is to define a class called "OneProblem" which has members for a, b, and op.   You create a single 'Vector<OneProblem>' and as you read the file you create a OneProblem object for each line of the source.  Then, at run time you either pick a random math problem, or loop through all the OneProblem objects, or you generate a completely random OneProblem from the random number generator.   Something like:

```
class OneProblem {
    public int a = 0;
    public int b = 0;
    public int op = 0;

    public OneProblem(int _a, int _op, int _b) {
        a =_a;
        b = _b;
        op = _op;
    }
}

class MathProblems {

    Vector<OneProblem> problems = new Vector<OneProblem>();

    //...lot of your other code here as well....

    workQuestion(OneProblem problem) {
        switch (problem.op) {
        case 0: 
            add(problem.a, problem.b);
            break;
        case 1: 
            subtract(problem.a, problem.b);
            break;
        case 2:
            multiply(problem.a, problem.b);
            break;
        case 3:
             divide(problem.a, problem.b);
             break;
        }
    }
}
```

You file reader needs to read each line and parse the first and second values out of the line, as well as (I presume) the operand between them.  Read the line, and search for the operand, and separate the integer before and the integer after.  Then as you read each line, construct an instance of `OneProblem` to match each line.  Now you are set to run.

When presenting the math questions, you loop through the values from `i=0` to `i<problems.size()`.  If there was no file read, those vectors will have no entries and so it will fall through.  After you finish the vectors, or if the vectors are empty, present math questions with random values.

```
if (problems.size()>0) {
    for (int i=0; i<problems.size(); i++) {
        OneProblem selProblem = problems.get(i);
        workQuestion(selProblem);
    }
}
else {
    workQuestion(new OneProblem({{random a}}, {{random op}}, {{random b}}));
}
```

Fill in the appropriate method for 'askQuestion'.  This is represented above as a loop, but maybe you want to pick a random one of the test values for presentation?  Then pick a reasonable random value for i in that range, and get the problem out of the vectors.

Comment: Ok gotcha. so basically the if is the ints from the txt file and the else will be my current randomMath problems? So this would be done in the public void run method from the MathProblems class?

Comment: I have filled in the method 'workProblem' to show you how you use the object, and renamed the class 'OneProblem' because the previous name was too close to your main class.

Comment: Hey thank you for your help, Just wanted to let you know I am working on making this work with your explanation.

Comment: by the way what is op referring to?

Comment: The member 'op' holds and integer where 0 stands for 'add', 1 stands for 'subtract' etc.   The `{{random op}}` and the bottom is just pseudocode saying that you should use some mechanism to pick a random mathematical operation: +, -, *, / or whatever.   If this works for you, check the "accepted answer" check mark.

Comment: so your saying do away with MathProblems.java all together.

Comment: MathProblems is the class that holds all the individual OneProblem objects.

Answer (score 0):

In your `filereader` method, you have this line, in a loop:

```
    int nextInt = textfile.nextInt();
```

But the sample text that you show contains '+' characters between your numbers, and I see no code present to take that into account.

To fix, you can either define '+' as a delimiter on your `Scanner` object, or make sure your loop reads it as a string.

Comment: Ok thanks that makes sense. I changed the txt file to show 1 2 3 4 etc. So if i want to say hey java program if a txt file exist use the ints from it and sum them, else run the program as normal just producing the random math problems. question "click for answer" answer  "click for next question" etc

Comment: Then you will need some code that determines if the file exists or not and takes the appropriate action. There's several ways to do this, but I'm sure that if you think about it for a bit, and have a look at what happens when you try to create a `Scanner` for a file that does not exist, you will figure it out.